# Swift equivalent of Unity3d Coroutines?

Tags: swift, unity-game-engine, swift3, async-await, coroutine

Looking how to build something similar in Swift 3.

I'm used to using this sort of architecture in Unity3d, perhaps there isn't anything similar to handle async data. I've heard of completion blocks + using protocols/delegates to pass data in Swift but I thought it'd be easier to have a public function that gets the data and then use a coroutine to wait until all the data is in the VC to start things up.

Here is C# code I'd use to create them:

```C#
List<Int> data = new List<Int>;

private IENumerator get_data() 
{ 
    run_async_func_to_get_data();

    while(data.count == 0) 
    {
       yield return null;
    }

    yield break;
}


private IENumerator start_game()
{
   yield return get_data();
   yield return use_data();
}

void Start() 
{
    StartCoroutine(start_game);
}
```

Comment: For us coders who haven't touched C# for a while, could you give a description of what this code does? It'll help us to give you an answer.

Comment: Coroutines like this are a Unity specific thing, not a C# specific thing.

Comment: Side note: for language/feature conversions please don't tag source language (C# in this case) as people with C# knowledge will not be able to help or even reason about the question (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316809/proper-tagging-for-language-conversion-questions).

Comment: I am not sure about the C# code but I would bet the Swift version is GCD.

Comment: And the same can be probably implemented using promises (or completion handlers).

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Actually no, the basic `yield return` capability is a [C# native feature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) for quickly implementing iterators. Unity just provided a nice game scripting framework around this...

Comment: @Wikkle_A Keep in mind that Unity's scripts are entirely single threaded. C#'s native threading isn't used, because that would require scripts to be designed for thread safety. Coroutines are a workaround that simulates concurrency, without actual any multithreading going on (thus no performance benefit). Applying coroutines to Swift wouldn't make sense, because Swift code isn't specifically meant to be run on only a single thread. You have the full power of multithreading and Grand Central Dispatch available to you.

Comment: @Alexander thanks for the heads up! :) Appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Swift do not currently support *[Unity/C# style coroutines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx)* (i.e., `yield return` style constructs). Such feature is pretty cool by the way ;-)

Having said that, you might want to take a look in the [Async framework](https://github.com/duemunk/Async) for a somewhat valid alternative (if you are really looking for async/await abstractions):

> Syntactic sugar in Swift for asynchronous dispatches in Grand Central Dispatch

As for Swift native support, we might need to [wait for Swift ≥ 5](http://ericasadun.com/2016/07/29/chris-lattner-on-wrapping-up-swift-3-starting-swift-4/) for something like that to come along:

> Actors, async/await, atomicity, memory model, and related topics. This area is highly desired by everyone, as it will open the door for all sorts of new things on the client, server and more. We plan to start formal discussions about this in Phase 2, but it is unfortunately crystal clear that a new concurrency model won’t be done in time for the Swift 4 release. This is simply because it will take more than a 12 months to design and build, and we want to make sure to take time to do it right. It also makes sense for the memory ownership model to be better understood before taking this on.

Comment: Side note: please make sure you are answering about Unity3d coroutines and not C#'s `async`/`await`.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thanks for the heads up! Those concepts can be tricky to [set apart sometimes](https://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2013/11/29/async-yield-return)...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov actually in the [next major release version](https://forum.unity3d.com/forums/experimental-scripting-previews.107/) they are implementing async/await so expect the yield return coroutines to be phased out in favor of the new style.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Good to know! I always felt that *yield/async/await* to be too overlapping to eventually coexist in the same game programming paradigm.