# Which value types in Swift supports copy-on-write?

Tags: swift, struct, collections, value-type, copy-on-write

I read about copy-on-write implementation for Array in Swift [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array).

> Arrays, like all variable-size collections in the standard library, use copy-on-write optimization. Multiple copies of an array share the same storage until you modify one of the copies. When that happens, the array being modified replaces its storage with a uniquely owned copy of itself, which is then modified in place. Optimizations are sometimes applied that can reduce the amount of copying.

I was wondering if you have any information about which structure supports copy-on-write.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Copy-on write is supported for `String` and all collection types - `Array`, `Dictionary` and `Set`.

Besides that, compiler is free to optimize any struct access and effectively give you copy-on-write semantics, but it is not guaranteed.

Comment: "not guaranteed" is one way to put it.  If you want copy-on-write semantics, you use `isKnownUniquelyReferenced(&ref)` explicitly.  (also you "must only call this function from mutating methods with appropriate thread synchronization"; note that text does not point to how the standard unsynchronized collections manage to avoid violating this. [Nor does this official doc](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/OptimizationTips.rst#advice-use-copy-on-write-semantics-for-large-values))  https://marcosantadev.com/copy-write-swift-value-types/

Comment: I don´t think its a compiler feature. Nowhere says that.