# Do we have to implement copy on write behavior for our custom types?

Tags: swift, copy-on-write

In Swift, collections are implicitly implemented with [copy on write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) behavior; However, we don't get it for free in our custom types.

**My main question is:**

*Regardless of how to achieve it*, is it a good idea to do for our custom types? Why/Why not?

**Moreover:**

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45253311/5501940), even the built-in types (but not collections) provided from the Swift standard library do *not* implement it which could be an indication that we don't have to do it. Even so, is there any advantage of doing it?

Comment: That depends on your custom type. – If you can build on the existing types with COW then that is surely the safer and easier approach.

Comment: Thanks @MartinR. "That depends on your custom type" that's what I'd like to know, are there standards to decide it? Hope it's not too broad...

Comment: There is probably no one-fits-all answer. Can you be more specific? What  kind and amount of data does your type hold? Do you need value semantics at all (otherwise use a class)? Can use *use* the existing COW types or not?

Comment: @MartinR for instance I have a struct (model without even functions) which contains about 20 property of various types, such as `Array`, `Double`, `Bool`, and yes at certain points I copy it. At this point, would it be a good idea to implement cow for it?

Comment: I would first evaluate if you really need value semantics. If not: use a class and you are done.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/24232845/1187415, which quotes from an older version of the Swift Language Reference: “*The structure’s primary purpose is to encapsulate a few relatively simple data values.*”

Answer (score 1):

You do not *have* to do it, but it can be a worthwhile optimization if you have the resources and need to do so. Ask yourself the following questions:

- Is my datatype copied often (i.e. applicability)?
- Is it easy enough to implement CoW in reasonably time (i.e. viability)?
- Does my application benefit from these optimizations (i.e. return of investment)?

Probably, in most applications it is not necessary and the users will not notice the difference. In some specific cases it might be applicable, but be critical. Remember:

> Premature performance optimization is the root of all evil ~ Donald Knuth